# Allow Shortcut keys to be handled by parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, keypress

**Scenario :**  I have created a Form(`Mainform`) which is the parent form or host form of the application -like your main screen in Outlook.

I have created a BarItem(<kbd>Help</kbd> ) under Menu Bar item and assigned a shortcut key <kbd>F1</kbd> using the Shortcut property.

But if any other form other than `Mainform` gets focus,the shortcut key does not reach the `Mainform`. How do I solve this?

I cant afford to subscribe keypress events for all the forms being launched from my `Mainform`.

**Similar scenario:** For example, when you go to any window in Microsoft Outlook and press <kbd>F1</kbd> , it will launch a  help window irrespective of the form being opened.I want similar behaviour.

Comment: just try to create a short-cut to all forms you created.

Comment: @spajce: Shortcut property is associated to a BarItem which is a private control in ParentForm. How do I create shortcut from all forms in order to redirect to ParentForm?

Comment: could you show your code handeling the event on the parent form?

Comment: @JensKloster: I have not written any handler for shortcut key press. .Net takes care of handling them . You need to just assign the shortcut key for the menu item.

Comment: @Rockstart I understand. but when I had this problem i used a solution much like the one spajce provided. It might not be an elegant solution, but i works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a message filter might help and is an adquate approach to use in your case.
Take a look at these:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx

Here is an example of a message filter for the up and down arrow keys
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257039/818321

Answer (score 1):

On the mainform (parent form if you will) make sure the property `KeyPreview` is set to true

Comment: KeyPreview is set to true. But it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this as I stated from my comment, just use the `KeyUp Event` to all your `Form` and the Properties is must be `KeyPreview = true`

```
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already have more than 200 child forms that will be launched from ParentForm. It is tough for me to introduce this code in all the classes.

Comment: How about creating a base class and overriding Keyup event there and all my child forms will be derived from this base class.?

Comment: you can try that. but i guess seems that is difficult but you can try.